# Cross-validation for RMSE

Tags: cross-validation, rms

The formula I have for cross-validation error is the following:
$$
\hat{R}_{CV}(f) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N L\left( y_i, \hat{f}^{-k(i)}(x_i) \right)
$$

where $\hat{f}^{-k(i)}$ is the model trained with $x_i$ excluded from the training set and $L$ is a loss function. Note that $k(i)$ is not necessarily injective e.g for 10-fold cross-validation $k(i)$ maps each training sample to one of the 10 folds $\{1,...,10\}$.

For variance I have the following:
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (L_i - \bar{L})^2
$$

where
$$
L_i = L(y_i, f^{-k(i)}(x_i)) \\
\bar{L} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N L_i
$$

I want to use root mean squared error which is:
$$
RMSE(f) = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - f(x_i))^2}{N}}
$$

My problem is that I am not sure how to adapt these formulas to RMSE. To calculate the variance it seems that I need to be able to decompose my error function to a sum of $L_i$ but I cannot do that because of the square root. How can I calculate the variance if my loss function is RMSE?

Comment: You seem to be using leave-one-out-CV - in which case the loss for the ith fold should be the same as the absolute difference between y_i and the model's prediction.  I think your formulas for the variance then just go through as normal?

Comment: Well not really, $k(i)$ is not necessarily injective. It maps each training sample to the subset that does not include that particular point. i.e for 10-fold it maps each training sample to {1,..,10}

Comment: @AndreasG. please make that clear in the text of your question: give a definition of $k(i)$. Then I'll provide an answer to your question.

Comment: @Jim I've made the change

Comment: @Jim No they are all of roughly the same size. It's non-injective because you can have $i \neq j$ s.t $k(i)=k(j)$ i.e two different samples mapped to the same set

Comment: Misread it, sorry. Point I was *trying* to make is: $k: [N] \to [10]$ *is* (assumed) surjective, i.e. each validation fold (set) contains at least one index $i \in [N] := \{1,2,..., N\}$. We're talking standard K-fold cross-validation, right? In words: each observation occurs exactly once in a validation fold.

Comment: @Jim Yes that's correct - it's a standard K-fold cross-validation. So roughly equal sized validation folds. But I wouldn't exclude the possibility that maybe one of the formulas I was given has a mistake. I think $\hat{R}_{CV}$ is correct but maybe one of the others has a mistak. Or maybe it's only suitable for loss functions that can be decomposed to a sum of $L_i$

Comment: I returned to your question today, but I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. Why can't you just substitute $f^{-k(i)}(x_i)$ for $f(x_i)$ in your expression for $\text{RMSE}(f)$?

Comment: @Jim Yes I can do that but my main problem is the variance, as I explain in my last sentence. For example what is $\bar{L}$? If I were calculating $MSE(f)$ without the square root, then it seems that $\bar{L}$ would be the $MSE$ where $L_i=(y_i-f^{-k(i)}(x_i))$. If you can just explain how to calculate the variance for RMSE in standard k-fold cross-validation(either in words or with formulas) then I will accept the answer